# The removeCommand is not working for the toolbar commands - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

The removeCommand and removeAllCommand is not working. If i put it in a button action listener removeCommand(command) works but removeAllcommand() is not working?
Is it a bug? Please check it out. Thankyou

```
Command d = new Command("back") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        }
};
f.setBackCommand(d);
f.getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar(d);
//Either of these two doesnt remove above back command...
 f.removeAllCommands();
f.removeCommand(d);
```

If i put it in action listener, one of them work

```
Button add = new Button("remove");
    add.addActionListener((e) -> {
        f.removeCommand(d);// it removes back command
        f.removeAllCommands(); // it doesnt work
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to revalidate the Form

```
Button add = new Button("remove");
add.addActionListener((e) -> {
            f.removeAllCommands();
            f.revalidate();
});
```